# How to register a custom URL scheme that opens the app when placed into safari

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard

I am trying to get to my keyboard's containing app from the keyboard extension itself. I have been following [this](https://kitefaster.com/2016/07/13/how-to-open-ios-app-with-custom-url/) tutorial but I am not sure if there is something I am missing.

[This is what my info.plist looks like for the containing app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8TYN.png)

I have not adjusted the info.plist of the extension.

When I open safari and enter in the custom url, it says:
 "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

Am I setting the identifier and scheme name properly? They can be whatever I want them to be as long as I spell it right when I need to use it right?

Answer (score 0):

Did You tried this , it allows you to DepLinking your App with custom URL and Open App from Safari

```
https://github.com/ijoshsmith/swift-deep-linking
```